# How to preserve form data when Error Generate on nodejs-Express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

How to preserve form data when errors occurs. Generally when form submit the page reloads. I am using handlesbars, express-validator, connect-flash.
Here is My code of Regestration:

```
//Register User
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;


    //Validation
    req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid!').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required!').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Minimum Length of Password is 1!').isLength({min: 1});
    req.checkBody('password2', 'Password do not match!').equals(req.body.password);


    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if(errors){
//want some help here by which if any error generate then all value is automatically filled. So that everytime there is no need to fill full form
        res.render('register', {
            errors: errors
        });
    }else{
//Here Success Part Code runs

    }
});
```

**And this code is of view part(register.handlebars)**
    //Any help will be appreciated.
**This Page is of handlebars. Littlebit confuse about displaying the old data to the form if form generates error**
    Register

```
    {{#if errors}}
        {{#each errors}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{msg}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
    <form method="post" action="/custom/register">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Userame">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm-Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: you mean, the server fetches all the data from the view, irrespective of the fact that there is error in it or not. And inside the server side file you are checking the data is valid or not. Then you are printing out the error into the view. And you want to keep the right data on your next form submission. Isn't that right?

Comment: Simply I want that when there is some validation error the whole form fileds have to fill. So rather than filling all fields is there any solution by which all other fields remain same or value is injected so that only the error field value have to fill not all

Comment: you can use a json object and store all the form fields that are valid and return it. So you can capture it in the view part and fill it there using html logic

Comment: store the json object from req.body. Say you created one named obj_not_error. Pass this object during your render method along with the errors and publish those json object in the view.   res.render('register', {
            errors: errors, obj_not_error:obj_not_error
        });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    //Register User
    router.post('/register', function(req, res){
        var name = req.body.name;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var username = req.body.username;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var password2 = req.body.password2;


    //fields value holder
        var form = {
            nameholder: req.body.name,
            usernameholder: req.body.username,
            emailholder: req.body.email
        };


        //Validation
        req.checkBody('name', 'Name is required!').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required!').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid!').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required!').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required!').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password', 'Minimum Length of Password is 1!').isLength({min: 1});
        req.checkBody('password2', 'Password do not match!').equals(req.body.password);


        var errors = req.validationErrors();
        if(errors){
            res.render('register', {
                errors: errors,
    form:form
            });
        }else{
    //Here Success Part Code runs

        }
    });

//register.handlebars page
//just add value with holder

    <h2 class="page-header">Register</h2>
    {{#if errors}}
        {{#each errors}}
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{msg}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
    <form method="post" action="/custom/register">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="{{form.nameholder}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Userame" value="{{form.usernameholder}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" value="{{form.emailholder}}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Confirm-Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm-Password">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: This answer is only code without any explanation of what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the form data back to the client, so it is available in the user's browser.

```
res.render('register', {
  errors: errors,
  formData: {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    username: username
  }
});
```

Then, modify your Handlebars template so it uses those values:

```
<form method="post" action="/xad/register">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" value="{{ name }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Userame" value="{{ username }}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm-Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i think i also done the same task. anyways thanks for giving support. I would like to ask one more thing that I am using Connect-flash. So req.flash('error_msg', 'your handy Message') works fine before res.redirect() but same thing won't work on res.render.

Comment: My code is res.render('register', {
      errors: req.flash('error_msg'),
      form: form
     });

Comment: You should probably create another question so someone who knows Connect-flash can help you out.  Anyway, maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233950/1822918